# Liferay 7 - Service builder - JSON restful service is not shown

Tags: java, rest, service, liferay

I'm currently working in Liferay 7 and trying to build my first service for the portal.

For this I have created a new service builder model, added my first simple method, added necessary annotations and try now to deploy the webservice. But the json service seems not to be correctly registerd. I cannot see any entry under "http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws".

My code looks as follows (only service interface and implementation):

**ServiceInterface:**

```
@AccessControlled
@JSONWebService()
@OSGiBeanProperties(property =  {"json.web.service.context.name=dynamicdataasset","json.web.service.context.path=DynamicDataAsset"}, service = DynamicDataAssetService.class)
@ProviderType
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.PORTAL, rollbackFor = {PortalException.class, SystemException.class})
public interface DynamicDataAssetService extends BaseService {


/**
* Returns the OSGi service identifier.
*
* @return the OSGi service identifier
*/
public java.lang.String getOSGiServiceIdentifier();
```

}

**ServiceImpl:**

```
@ProviderType
@JSONWebService("dynamic-data-assets")
public class DynamicDataAssetServiceImpl extends DynamicDataAssetServiceBaseImpl {

/**
 * Test method to see if the service is available.
 * @return
 */
@JSONWebService(value = "get-availability-of-service", method = "GET")
public String getAvailabilityOfService() {
    return "Service is available";
}
```

}

**service.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_0_0.dtd">

<service-builder package-path="eu.gerhards.liferay.dynamic.data.list.assets">
<namespace>DynamicDataAsset</namespace>
<entity local-service="true" name="DynamicDataAsset" remote-service="true" uuid="false" human-name="DynamicDataAsset">
...
```

I followed the tutorial which can be found here: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/service-builder-web-services.

Can anyone tell me, what is wrong and point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot

Udo

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Please see the example here][1]    After service build you will get the serviceImple class to implement rest web service..
        please choose the context name what you have provided in service.xml file ex :-<namespace>xxx_mh</namespace>
```

***********Here is sample code**************

```
@ProviderType
        public class xxxServiceImpl extends xxxServiceBaseImpl {
        @ProviderType
        public class xxxServiceImpl extends xxxServiceBaseImpl {

            public JSONObject UrmethodName(long xxId, Date startDate,
                    Date endDate) {
        /*****Your implementation ***/
        return responseData;
        }
        }



      ************Here is Service.xml file for reference **************


 <entity local-service="true" name="Xxxx" table="xxx_xxx" remote-service="true" >
```